# Invoking super class implementation of the method after setting some attributes in the subclass

Tags: java, android

I am making a baseactivity for an Android app. I need to set some attributes in the onCreate method in the subclass before calling the super class implementation of it which does the work. So is this bad practice? To set attributes in the subclass then call the super class implementation of the method where you set them?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I wouldn't say that it is necessarily bad practice.  It's fairly common in object-oriented languages, in fact.  Think of it this way, often you want to override or extend some superclass behavior.  When you do so, you have three basic options:

1. Don't call the superclass version at all.  For instance, if you want to completely replace the old behavior.
2. Call the superclass version, and then do some extra things.  If you want to preserve the old behavior and then add your own extensions to it.
3. Do some extra things, and then call the superclass version (and then maybe do some additional things afterwards).  If you want to influence the old behavior without having to completely replace/reimplement it.

Of course, there is an increasing amount of brittleness as you move from 1 -> 2 -> 3.  If you completely bypass the superclass method as in #1 then there is very little chance that a future update to the superclass will break your code.  If you call the superclass method and then add your own code, then there is a greater possibility that future changes in the superclass will cause your code to break, particularly if your code is relying on any side-effects caused by execution of the superclass code.  And finally, if you add code that influences the superclass method by injecting side-effects before it is called there there is an even greater chance that your code will one day be broken by an update to the superclass, because the author of the superclass has no way of knowing what side-effects you are using to influence its behavior and is under no obligation to continue responding to them in the same way.

So there's a trade-off to be made.  Option #3 may be the fastest way to solve the problem, but it is also the most likely to be inadvertently broken by future changes to the superclass because it relies upon various assumptions about how the superclass implementation behaves.  Whether this is a serious problem or not depends upon things like how often the superclass is subject to change, how likely it is that the behavior that you are relying upon will be changed, how much control you have over if/when you accept a modified version of the superclass, whether or not you have ownership over the code for both the superclass and the subclass(es), how difficult it would be to switch to option #2 or option #1, and so on.

Ultimately it's not so much a question of good practice vs. bad practice, it's more about understanding the pros and cons of each option and picking the one that best suits your project.

Comment: @artoh: Thank you, so is there a way to make a base activity that sets some properties before calling the super class implementation of it? Is it better to make a Utilities class and add some methods that each class invokes instead?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to set some attributes in the
>   onCreate method in the subclass before
>   calling the super class implementation
>   of it which does the work. So is this
>   bad practice?

Yes it is a bad practice.

Comment: Okey, do you have some suggestions to how I can do that then?

Comment: @Andreas: set them through the constructor via a call to super.

Comment: @techiServices: But is it normal or can I override the onCreate-method in the baseactivity?

Comment: It might be more useful to explain why it's bad practice.